# Storyboard change Target Control

Tags: windows-phone-7, storyboard

I have created a Storyboard through Expression Blend. The Storyboard animates an Ellipse as a sortof placeholder for now. Now that I am back in Visual Studio, how can I make the Storyboard do the exact same thing but to a different control? I have a list of images:

```
private List<Image> items = new List<Image>();
```

Each object in items has been assigned with a name using the Name property:

```
 items[i].Name = i.ToString();
```

'i' in this case is the counter.

How do I therefore make the Storyboard target "one" specific object within the list for the moment. Later, I shall try to make the Storyboard do the same for all of them.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by having a Storyboard Completed event and changing the target using:

```
Storyboard.SetTargetName();
```